# How do I access SOAP headers in a Spyne srpc method?

Tags: soap, spyne

Forgive me if I am just being thick but the [Spyne documentation on headers](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/06_metadata.html) seems a bit thin and the link to the sample code is broken.  I think I found the sample code [here](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/authentication/server_soap.py) but it only seems to access the headers in a listener callback function. I need access to it in the srpc method if possible.

What I would like to do is something like this (*this does not work*):

```
class MyRequest(ComplexModel):
    Messages = Array(Unicode)

class MyHeader(ComplexModel):
    TrackingID = ByteArray

class MySoapService(ServiceBase):
    @srpc(MyRequest, _in_header=MyHeader)
    def PostMessages(req, hdr):
        logging.info(u'RECEIVED: {0:s}'.format(hdr.TrackingID))
```

If it helps, I am trying to replace a service written in .NET that just defines the message headers in the message contract like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyRequest
{
  [MessageHeader]
  public Guid TrackingID { get; set; }

  [MessageBodyMember]
  public String[] Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read header data from within an srpc function. @srpc is for existing functions that you don't want to touch. You should always use @rpc unless you know you need @srpc

Decorate your function using @rpc. This passes the rpc context (conventionally named ctx) as first argument to your function. Then, ctx.in_header is where you'll find the header data. You can also set ctx.out_header to alter outgoing response headers.

Also, pull requests for docs are pure gold to me :)

Comment: I will give this a try. I only used @srpc because that was in the getting started examples and I just extended from there.

This appears to be the best web services library right now for python and if I am going to be using it, I will try to contribute to the docs if I can.